# Delete Row/Post in WordPress database on submit

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to build (my first) a basic WordPress plugin that stores form data and one of the options I need is the ability to delete old form data. I've been experimenting with trying to get a simple query to work, but I keep getting an error message. The error reads **' Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/.. on line 5'**

So in theory when I click submit it should delete the post. Am I way off? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Plugin admin page -

```
<h1>Form Data</h1>


<form action="next.php" method="post">

<input type="submit">


</form>
```

Next.php

```
<?php

global $wpdb;

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = 42" ) );

?>
```

Comment: Not enough info (sample code) in you Q. But, you don't need `next.php`, the form can be processed in the admin page. Also, check http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation

Comment: May be this will work: Change this `$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = 42" ) );` to just `$wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = 42" );`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the code as is. It's not going to work because you are not including any supporting php files from Wordpress. So $wpdb is not defined, and therefor any functions you are calling on it are also not defined.

It looks like you are going about Wordpress plugin development incorrectly. Take a look at their docs and APi on their site.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Pulls in WordPress prerequisite code
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );

// Bring global variable $wpdb into local scope
global $wpdb;

// Run the database query
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = 42" ) );

?>
```

Comment: a short explanation of what this code does would be nice